# Why am I getting exceptions with this generic method for short and long but not int

Tags: c#, generics

I have these methods for finding the greatest common devisor

```cs
private static T GenGCD<T> (dynamic a, dynamic b)
        {
            // Absolute values are use to account for: a < 0 and/or b < 0; b > a            
            return (a, b) switch
            {
                (0, 0) => 0,
                (0, _) => Math.Abs(b),
                (_, 0) => Math.Abs(a),
                _ => GCD(b, a % b)
            };
        }

public static short GCD(this short a, short b) { return GenGCD<short>(a, b); }
public static int GCD(this int a, int b) { return GenGCD<int>(a, b); }
public static long GCD(this long a, long b) { return GenGCD<long>(a, b); }
```

Used like

```cs
short a = 270;
short b = 192;
short r = a.GCD(b)
```

or

```cs
int a= 270;
int b = 192;
int r = a.GCD(b)
```

or

```cs
long a = 270;
long b = 192;
long r = a.GCD(b)
```

it works when `a` and `b` are `int` but when they are `long` I get an exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) 
    at MathExtensions.GenGCD[T](Object a, Object b)
    at MathExtensions.GCD(Int64 a, Int64 b)
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object )
    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    at MathExtensions.GenGCD[T](Object a, Object b)
    at MathExtensions.GCD(Int64 a, Int64 b)
    at Program.Main()
```

and when they are `short` I get a different exception

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at MathExtensions.GenGCD[T](Object a, Object b)
   at MathExtensions.GCD(Int16 a, Int16 b)
   at Program.Main()
```

Why does it work for `int` but not `long` or `short`?

Comment: why are you using `dynamic` as input types - instead of `T`? (which would be the whole _point_ of generics?)

Comment: You should for sure not use `dynamic` as a means of writing code that works for one of exactly three specific known types.  Just write three overloads, one for each type. Your code will be easier to understand, statically typed, perform *much* better, and all around just not suck.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann The ```dynamic``` is because you can't use math operators on ```T``` and ```Math``` doesn't accept ```T```

Comment: @Servy I only put the three types because this is the point where I decided to test the code. I want it to work for all of c#'s integer types.

Comment: @Servy I did it this way because I don't want to have a bunch of duplicate code for each integer type.

Comment: `a % b` returns an `int` value, so it'll fail with `short`. You may use [`Math.DivRem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-5.0), but it doesn't work with `short`. Actually, you should read the first paragraph of [Arithmetic operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators) first

Comment: @master_ruko So is having code that doesn't work, is unmaintainable, doesn't make logical sense, performs orders of magnitude worse, worth trying to have slightly fewer lines of code?  You seem to vastly overestimate the cost of having a few extra lines of code and vastly underestimate the costs of everything you're using here.

Comment: @Servy Any feedback for how to improve my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it work for int but not long or short?

Since `0` is specifically an `int` and thus `0L` won't match it if `dynamic` is [involved](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y5nepj). You can check the IL [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoASAotJwGYACfBggdlIG9Sz89OPyuCATgAUASSgBZCDADGAC2EAGAJTKA3JwEjxU2QsUAZVRvIBfTp1pMAbHWAB7exjo7p84QBMAngDsIYNBk6ADcIDABXOGVeTRxmELDIuigAdzQ9Ujos7JysvlyC3MU6AF4APjoYBEikTML6gH1SioAzMKg4Ovqs0xMycxJTIA) and see that if `0` is switched on a `dynamic` it specifically checks that the value is an int 0, not any old 0.

I would suggest something along the lines of below. The key changes are:

1. Don't use `switch` (this avoids the main issue - that the `switch` is not acting as you'd like since the types don't align).
2. Change the recursion so the method calls itself  (not via `GCD`).

Also, as others suggested, consider avoiding `dynamic` altogether - and implementing separate methods for each type (e.g. one for `int`, another for `long`).

```
using System;
                    
public static class Program
{
    private static T GenGCD<T> (dynamic a, dynamic b) where T:struct
    {
        if (a == 0) {
            if (b == 0) {
                return (T)(object)0;
            }

            return Math.Abs(b);
        } 
        else if (b == 0)
        {
            return Math.Abs(a);
        }

        return GenGCD<T>((T)b, (T)(a % b));
    }

    public static short GCD(this short a, short b) { return GenGCD<short>(a, b); }
    public static int GCD(this int a, int b) { return GenGCD<int>(a, b); }
    public static long GCD(this long a, long b) { return GenGCD<long>(a, b); }
    public static Single GCD(this Single a, Single b) { return GenGCD<Single>(a, b); }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Single a= 99;
        Single b = 87;
        Single r = a.GCD(b);
        
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one method for `long` is probably enough for 99% of cases (maybe there are a couple cases where performance matter so much that difference between `Int32` and `Int64` is noticeable)... You can still have wrappers that simply cast resulting `long` to shorter type if that's critical...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yep, assuming you don't need floating point / decimal.

Comment: Sure, also I don't see how any floating point types would be useful for GCD... Since they can't represent most rational numbers (i.e. 1/3) it would be anyway limited to whole part... and for that BigInteger would be far safer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Arguably true, yes. But given https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.op_modulus?view=net-5.0 etc do exist, clearly some people use them. :)